# Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code? it says syntax error on my "if" command

Tags: python

```
x= float(input('num 1: ')) ; y= float(input('num 2: '));if(x>y): print('greater number is',x);else: print('greater number is',y)
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(currently running python 3.11.4)
[image]

expected to give results in format of greatest number

Comment: Please format your code into a code box so we can read it.

Comment: Perhaps you think that you are programming in javascript. Please update your question with properly formatted python code.

Comment: Don't do that.  The semicolon operator should be banished.  Put your statements on separate lines.

Comment: @TimRoberts The python i am running isn't allowing me code in multiple lines, says it needs to be all on one line

Comment: @quamrana No i am coding on python and this is the format i had used for a previous code and it worked

Comment: Just avoid semicolons and get a better python IDE. No one needs to do that. Have you seen any other python code? The vast majority of code on this site is formatted correctly.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
x = float(input('num 1: '))
y = float(input('num 2: '))
if x>y: 
    print('greater number is',x)
else:
    print('greater number is',y)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

To expand on the other answers, even if you can use the semicolon ";" in Python for multiple statements, it's limited to:

- A sequence of simple statements
  `print('a'); print('b'); print('c')`
- An initial clause followed by simple statements. When using clauses like `if`, `else`, `while`, etc. there can be only one clause present per line "mostly because [for multiple ifs] it wouldn’t be clear to which if clause a following else clause would belong"

Even if possible it's not recommended as the pythonic way of writing code uses whitespace (indentation or new lines) to separate them and is more readable.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html
https://www.askpython.com/python/semicolon-in-python

Comment: Hi I haven't downvoted, but I can point out many problems with your answer: 1) semi-colons are allowed with simple statements, not _only_ compound statements, e.g. `print('Hello'); print('World')`. 2) You say _but there can be only one block per line_, however the page you linked shows an example of one block that fails. The position of the block is important, and obviously there can't be two blocks in the first position. 3) _Pythonic_ usually refers to style choices favored by python programmers, indentation and new lines are mandatory and serve different purposes.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to point the incorrect parts. I disagree with 3, by definition it's not mandatory if you can do it in a different way using ;s